# When passing ampersand in the URI for file: schemes into ProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader() it fails

Tags: java, apache-camel

When using `ProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader()` to send a file using the "file" scheme to its destination, and the file path in the URI contains ampersands, it fails to deliver the file with the following errors.

> org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: 
>   file:///c%7C/IMM_SAN/Marketing/f77333bd-f96f-4873-b846-2f1dc5531a5a/2596/PB&J%20Generic%2007064782/transcoded/21726 
>   due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: 
>   file:///c%7C/IMM_SAN/Marketing/f77333bd-f96f-4873-b846-2f1dc5531a5a/25964/PB&J%20Generic%2007064782/transcoded/21726 
>   due to: Invalid uri syntax: no ? marker however the uri has & parameter separators. Check the uri if its missing a ? marker.

Spending a few days trying the different overloads to send the file `send()`, `sendBody()`, `sendBodyAndHeader()` and even `sendBodyAndHeaders()`.

I tried to `UrlEncoder.encode()` it before hand and of course a no go.

I even debugged the `URISupport.normalizeUri(String uri)` from the camel-core source and discovered something interesting.  Apparently no amount of encoding will do me any good before sending the body and header because it appears to be doing its own encoding and it appears to be totally incorrect.  I think this is a bug in `sendBodyAndHeader()`.  It encodes the ampersand back into the URI before sending it.  This is bad.  Why are we doing that?  We have an application that reads files from one department and are written to a share and another system automatically picking those file up and delivering it when processing on the file is finished.

See below camel `URISupport.normalizeUri(String uri)` method is encoding the URI here and this puts the ampersand back into the file path.

```
URI u = new URI(UnsafeUriCharactersEncoder.encode(uri));
```

So you see no amount of preprocessing on the file path in the URI is going to work at all because sendBodyAndHeader is going to do whatever it feels like doing.  I would like to add a new overload to this API to turn off normalization and just send the URI as is.  But wanted to check here to see if anybody has any less drastic options.  Please note this is a problem when ampersands are in the URI path for file schemes.

```
ProducerTemplate prod = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
destPath = destPath.replace(':', '|');
destPath = destPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
destPath = destPath.replaceAll("&", "%26");  // replace the ampersand
String query = "file:///" + destPath;
prod.sendBodyAndHeader(query, exchange.getIn().getBody(), Exchange.FILE_NAME, destFileName);
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And I assume you use Windows, if so which OS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CamelFileName header to avoid messing up the endpoint URI with the reserved character & if you really need that character in the file path.

This example would put a file into `c:\a&b`

```
public void sendAnyFile(Exchange e){
    ProducerTemplate pt = getContext().createProducerTemplate();
    pt.sendBodyAndHeader("file:///c:/",e.getIn().getBody(String.class), "CamelFileName", "a&b/hej.txt");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but "CamelFileName" is exactly what i am using, hence the Exchange.FILE_NAME.  This expands out to exactly that.  You know if it were up to me I would just replace the ampersand with something else but my superiors are telling me "it has to accept ampersand turn it around and retain the ampersand and deliver the file".  Anyway I stepped into source for sendBodyAndHeader() and discovered this normalizeURI was unconditionally being called even for "file:" type schemes.  This is a problem and it doesn't even seem to care about the header at all.

Comment: I did actually run the above code, before posting my answer, with Camel 2.10.3 and got the file sent to C:\a&b\hej.txt

But when you say it, I realize Exchange.FILE_NAME is the same as CamelFileName

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is, you have the file name with the ampersand.  This is not the problem.  The issue is that the ampersand is in the path which is in URI in the first parameter to sendBodyAndHeader().  I suppose I could parse the path part out and just hard code "file:///c:/" and prepend the path part to the file name in the last parameter.  This would merely be a work around to the issue but if it works I will be fine with it.

Comment: That was exactly my idea - put the amp in the file name header instead of the URI. The file name is not really a "file name", but a part of the total path.